# golang でパイプで渡された標準入力を次のパイプに渡したい

Tags: windows, go

例えば、

```
$ A | B | C
```

というパイプがあったととして

A の 標準出力を B で処理しつつ C にも渡したい場合
Bのソースコード内に

```
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
  txt := scanner.Text()
  // txt を処理
}
```

のようなことはできないのでしょうか？
上記のようにプログラミングすると、どちらか片方に出力されるようです。

Comment: `io.TeeReader(os.Stdin, os.Stdout)` を使うとか。`go/src/io/example_test.go` に `ExampleTeeReader()` という実装例があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

既にコメント欄で解決している様ですが、知見を残す為に。io.TeeReader を使うと Read 時に第一引数の Reader から読み取られ、読み取ったバッファが第二引数の Writer に書きだされ、呼び出し元にもバッファが返されます。

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r := io.TeeReader(os.Stdin, os.Stdout)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

質問の様に io.Copy で実装する場合、`io.Pipe` と `io.MultiWriter` を使う必要があります。

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        defer w.Close()
        io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(w, os.Stdout), os.Stdin)
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

※エラー処理が必要です。